# Why spatial pyramid uses pooling while feature pyramid uses convolution？

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, yolo, pooling

They seem to have the same purpose, which is to fuse features of different scales so that a set of feature maps contains both high semantics and high resolution.

Want to know the difference between pooling and convolution in CV